# Adding a Help file in Firemonkey applications

Tags: firemonkey, chm

I'm creating the help file for an application written in Delphi Firemonkey.
Unfortunately I have discovered that Firemonkey APPLICATION class doesn't have the HelFile property that the VCL equivalent has, so it seems to not be possible to include a help file with the application.
I would like to know if someone has dealt with this problem and which is the better strategy to solve this.
I thought to write a launcher in VCL console mode.
The launcher is started from the main application with some parameters including the help topic code.
This launcher links the HELP file, so the only thing it does is to start the help and then terminate itself. but this solution seems tricky to me.
I was wondering if a better solution exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've dived deeply into the source code, and although I don't fully understand it, I found some interesting things.  I don't have a custom help file to test with, but hopefully you can make this work.

The first interesting thing that I found is that there is a unit called `System.HelpIntfs`. That is, this is a `System` unit, not a `vcl` unit, so you'd expect it to be usable with FMX.

In order to call the Windows HTMLHelp system from FMX, you need to first call `GetHelpSystem()`, passing as an `out` parameter an `iHelpSystem`, `iHelpSystem2`, or `iHelpSystem3` variable.  You can then use the returned result to call for help.

However, when I tried this, it mostly failed, because the returned result is supposed to contain a list of help viewers, but that list was empty.  I then found that the list can be populated with one entry for the Windows HTMLHelp by using the unit `vcl.HtmlHelpViewer`.  What is interesting here is that, despite the name, *this unit has no vcl dependencies*!  The only units it uses are `System.Classes`, `System.HelpIntfs`, `System.SysUtils`, and `Winapi.Windows`.

`vcl.HtmlHelpViewer` creates the viewer object and registers it in its `Initialization` section, so all you have to do with this is include it.

I have assumed that you have populated your controls' .`HelpContext` or `HelpKeyword` properties.

Your code will need to be something like this:

```
unit Form1;

interface

uses System.HelpIntfs, Vcl.HtmlHelpViewer,   //Necessary
     winapi.Windows,FMX.Platform.Win,        //Only needed for the line with 'hook' in it.
     System.UITypes,                         //Just for F1 name.
     FMX.Types, FMX.Controls;                //You probably already have these two.
.
.
.
//Form's OnKeyUp event handler.
procedure Form1.FormKeyUP(Sender:TObject; var Key:Word; var KeyChar:Char; Shift:TShiftState);
var  o:    TFMXObject;
     Ctrl: TStyledControl absolute o;
     hs:   iHelpSystem; //Or iHelpSystem2 or iHelpSystem3.  See Delphi help for the differences.
const      HelpFileName = 'MyHelpFile.chm';
begin
  if (key=vkF1) and (Shift=[]) then begin
    o:=Focused.GetObject;        //Get the focussed control, that the user would be expecting help on.
    if o is TStyledControl then begin
      GetHelpSystem(hs);
      case WhatIWant of //pseudo-values now to show options
        IWantTOC:             hs.ShowTableOfContents;  //NB: This doesn't work, as we haven't provided a file name and this method doesn't take parameters.
        IWantTOC_thatWorks:   hs.hook(FormToHWND(self),HelpFileName,HH_DISPLAY_TOC,0)
        IWantContextHelp:     hs.ShowContextHelp(Ctrl.HelpContext,HelpFileName); 
        IWantKeywordHelp:     hs.ShowKeywordHelp(Ctrl.HelpKeyword,HelpFileName); //Untested, but doesn't crash.
        IWantSomethingElse:   ;//See Delphi help for other options.
      end; //case
    end;
  end;
end
```

Presumably you'll want to move some of that (such as the `HelpFileName` constant) somewhere else and add some more error checking, but this should give you the idea, and I hope you can get it working.

Comment: First a great thankyou for your efforts.
Unfortunately what you have written is quite obscure to me. 
I added the Vcl.HtmlHelpViewer unit, but the snippet of code you heve put above doesn't work and it is full of claimed errors by the IDE (Alexandria 11.3).

Comment: Let's go by order.
1. the statement 
    Ctrl: TStyledControl absolute TFMXObject; 
is absolutely unknown to me. Delphi Help refuses to find any kind of content with this declaration. Also it puts a red zigzag under the semicolon that closes it after the term "TFMXObject". The error message is E2088Variable name expected at line xxx

Comment: 2. the variable type iHelpSystem is completely unknown byt the IDE, as well as its variants iHelpSystem2 and iHelpSystem3. I repeat, I added the VCL unit to the uses clause.
3. the GetHelpSystem(hs) call is unknown to the IDE.

Comment: 3. the behavior of pseudocode "hs.ShowTableOfContents" is unknown byt the IDE;
4. the behavior of pseudo hs.hook(FormToHWND(self),HelpFileName,HH_DISPLAY_TOC,0) seems to be understood by the IDE, but the constant "HH_DISPLAY_TOC" is unknown. Also the fact that "seems" that the IDE understands something I recently learned that is not a guarantee that it is correct. Alexandria has a different behaviour from the precedent versions, and one a mitake is found, the other errors on the same object are not shown, probably for brevity.

Comment: I used Delphi 10.4.2, but I doubt that's the problem.  Alexandria is not different to earlier versions in not showing repeated mistakes. Did you add _all_ the units I listed?  iHelpSystem etc. are in the `System.HelpIntfs` unit.  I overlooked adding common units `FMX.Types` and `FMX.Controls`, the former of which has `TFMXObject`.

Comment: I made an error when transcribing the code.  The line with "absolute" should have read `Ctrl: TStyledControl absolute o;`. For `absolute`, see the Delphi help topic **Variables**.  It places a variable (Ctrl) in the same memory location as the other variable (o).

Comment: Sorry, my first comment's reference to `TFMXObject` was misplaced; I thought you were saying that the IDE didn't recognise `TFMXObject`.  Those units do need to be included though.

Comment: Actually, you don't need `WinAPI.Windows` nor `FMX.Platform.Win`.  I used them for more direct attempts, but they aren't needed in the final result.  I have removed those from the code above.

Comment: OK. Now it seems that the IDE can recognize all the elements. All the Units were declared in the USES clause. Changing the order in which the CTRL line is written has changed everything.
The only thing that remains unreckoned by the IDE is the constant HH_DISPLAY_TOC in the statement of the pseudocode at "IWantTOC_thatWorks".
By the way, which is the difference between "IWantTOC" and "IWantTOC_thatWorks"?
Let me guess, one is a TOC alone and one is a TOC on the left side of the help?

Comment: Arrgh!  Sorry, `HH_DISPLAY_TOC` is in the `WinAPI.Windows` unit, and 'FormToHWND()` is in the `FMX.Platform.Win` unit, so you _do_ need those two for that line (only).  The `IWantTOC` line _should_ be the way that you call the help contents, but for the reason I gave in the code, that doesn't work, so `IWantTOC_thatWorks` is an alternative that works.

Comment: What I would like to achieve is that I put a number into the control's properties for the helpContext, and when I press F1 the help pops up and the correct page is shown. Also a show up if I put a clickable HELP button is fine, also because it is better. 
Let's presume I have a panel for data entry with many controls on it (TEdits, Labels and so on).
I want to open a help page that summarizes the PANEL, not the single control. I  should insert the same HelpContext to every control on the panel. Should a click over a HELP button better and more elegant? Thanks for this ... help.

Comment: BTW I approved the edit of the post. Sorry for my many typos. I had noticed that it is impossible to put the word HELP in the description, for some reason this system refuses to get the title if it contains the word "help". This is the reason I changed with the word "aide".

Comment: Now it is very late and tomorrow I have to bring my daughter to the doctor very early in the morning. I will read the followup tomorro.
Thanks for all the help you gave me.

Comment: Your goal is the intent of the `IWantContextHelp` line, but because I didn't know what the numbers (or keywords) were for individual topics in the help files I was testing with (including FMX.CHM), I couldn't test that.  For your own help file, you should be able to use valid numbers.  And yes, I believe that you should add the same number (for the panel help) to each of the controls on that panel.  If you want a button for help, again, I would put the number in its `HelpContext` field.  I assume that by clicking that button, it would have the focus in time for this to work.

Comment: I refuse to think that I'm the only one who has hit my head on this issue.
You should make a component for FMX applications and sell it.
How many "gazillion" programmers have the problem to deal with help in firemonkey applications? Moreover with your skills you could create a component that could work in all the possible FMX friendly environments (Apple, Linux etc.)
I think it will be very (but VERY) successful.

Comment: @SergioBonfiglio, does the context help work for you?  I've been hoping to hear from you that you've got it working satisfactorily.
Thanks for the compliment.  Mobile applications typically have their help built into the program (and even in Windows, that's what I tend to do, but then I mostly program for myself), which may be why there hasn't been more demand for this.

Comment: Of course it worked. You saved my day.
All that I need is to add this simple event handler under any HELP button I will put on a form:


procedure MyUnit.HelpButton0001Click(Sender: TObject);
var hs : iHelpSystem;
begin
   GetHelpSystem(hs);
   hs.ShowContextHelp(NumberOfHelpPage,HelpFileName);
end;

and voilà !! It works as a piece of cacke.
But also the other longer routine is fantastic. 
I have no words to say enough thankyous.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad that it did work.  Would you mind marking it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Of course. It just needs to understand how to do it... Let me see....
OK. I think I did it.